# How to display flashdata in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Following is my view I am catching the data from the model and displaying on the view using 
flashdata in codeigniter

My Controller cart.php

```
 public function coupon(){
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $this->input->post("products_in_cart"); $i++) {

        if (!empty($this->input->post("coupn-" . $i))) {

            $couponname = $this->input->post("coupn-" . $i);
            $products_id = $this->input->post("product_id" . $i);

            $data = $this->home_model->getCoupon($couponname, $products_id);
            $data1 = 'hello';
            $info = array(
                "PromotioanlName" => $data->PromotionalName,
            );
        } else {

            $info = 'Thers in no value<br>';
        }



    }
    echo $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $info);
    redirect(site_url('cart'));
}
```

My view cart.php

```
 $message = $this->session->flashdata('message');
  print_r($message);
```

But my problem is that my data is overwritten by the next value

Comment: "overwritten by the next value" means? there isn't any `set_flashdata('message');` is used after it, right?

Comment: It is taking from data from the loop and storing it in the array and then displaying that array

Comment: What is given the output `print_r($message);` currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `for` loop, you have written `if` and in `if`, `$info` is an array and in `else`, `$info` is string!! Thus in loop when condition of `if` will be true, it'll be worked as an array and it'll be overwritten if condition will be true again in second recurs of loop!! And while condition false, it'll return string that will overwrite your array..

Try by using, `$info[]` instead of `$info`.. May be it solved your problem..

```
public function coupon(){
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $this->input->post("products_in_cart"); $i++) {

        if (!empty($this->input->post("coupn-" . $i))) {

            $couponname = $this->input->post("coupn-" . $i);
            $products_id = $this->input->post("product_id" . $i);

            $data = $this->home_model->getCoupon($couponname, $products_id);
            $data1 = 'hello';
            $info[] = array(
                "PromotioanlName" => $data->PromotionalName,
            );
        } else {

            $info[] = 'Thers in no value<br>';
        }



    }
    echo $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $info);
    redirect(site_url('cart'));
}
```